# Too many arguments in function call. c++

Tags: c++, function, class, object, vector

So my goal is to pass this vector *vector 'Beer' allBeers* to a function *UnitedStatesBeer::getBeerTop()*, but when I try to do that, I get the error that there's too many arguments in function call, or my object is not initialized.

How do I fix this? Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class RatingCalculator
{
public:
     virtual void showCountryTop() = 0;
     virtual void getCountryTop() {};
};

class Beer
{
public:
    string name;
    string rating;
    string country;
    string alc;
    string type;
};

class UnitedStatesBeer : public RatingCalculator
{
private:
    string name;
    string rating;
    string country;
    string alc;
    string type;
public:
    void showCountryTop() {};
    void getCountryTop(vector<Beer> allBeers){};

int main()
{
        ifstream file("beer.txt");
        Beer currentBeer;
        vector<Beer> allBeers;

        for (int i = 0; !file.eof(); i++)
        {
            getline(file, currentBeer.name, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.rating, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.country, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.alc, '\t');
            getline(file, currentBeer.type, '\n');

            allBeers.push_back(currentBeer);    //copy all the information to allBeers vector 
        }
        file.close();

        /*if I do it this way*/
        UnitedStatesBeer UsReassign;          
        UsReassign->getCountryTop(allBeers);   //<- expression (UsReassign) must have pointer type/ Using uninitialized memory

    //  RatingCalculator* UsReassign = new UnitedStatesBeer();
    //  UsReassign-> getCountryTop(allBeers);  //<- too many arguments in function call


    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us, something which we can copy-paste and try ourselves without needing to edit or modify it in any way. Also please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question (as text), as often there could be helpful informational notes that could give hints to the problem.

Comment: A hint though: To override a virtual function, the function signature (like e.g. arguments) must be *exactly* the same as in the base class.

Comment: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Why does `UnitedStatesBeer` have a `country` property? I would expect to see `class UnitedStatesBeer : public Beer`, since beer from the US is a kind of beer (well, at least some of it is) and not a kind of calculator.

Comment: Note that you are not overriding your virtual correctly. `RatingCalculator::getCountryTop()` vs. `UnitedStatesBeer::getCountryTop(vector<Beer> allBeers)`.

Comment: I'm missing the closing brace and semicolon `};` of `class UnitedStatesBeer`. As such, you are declaring `main()` as a member function of `UnitedStatesBeer`. Probably not what you wanted to do...

Comment: IMHO, you should change your design.  Use inheritance for *is-a* relationships and composition for *has-a* relationships.  A `UnitedStatesBeer` is not a calculator, it is a kind of beer; so `UnitedStatesBeer` should inherit from `Beer`.  Look at the the two classes, they have a lot in common.  Maybe the calculator should be a separate class that *contains* different beers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Since you want to override virtual function, you'd want to match function definition in Base Class aka `RatingCalculator` with the one in  `UnitedStatesBeer`. This is how it should look in `RatingCalculator` :

```
  virtual void getCountryTop(vector<Beer> allBeers) {};
```

and in `UnitedStatesBeer`

```
 void getCountryTop(vector<Beer> allBeers){};
```

Secondly, since you want to get Top beers, you may want to pass by reference, by adding `&` in front of variable `beers`.

Thirdly, 
`UsReassign->getCountryTop(allBeers);   //<- expression (UsReassign) must have pointer type/ Using uninitialized memory..`
This is happening because UsReassign is a object and NOT a pointer. Objects are referenced with `.` instead of `->`.

And Lastly,
`//  UsReassign-> getCountryTop(allBeers);  //<- too many arguments in function call`
This is happening because function `getCountryTop()` with NO arguments is being called. Steps mentioned in "Firstly" should fix it.

Comment: after writing RatingCalculator::getCountryTop(vector<Beer> allBeers), I get an error: C2065: 'Beer': undeclared identifier

Comment: and C2923: 'std::vector': 'Beer' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Comment: @tendor Try putting `Beer` class before `RatingCalculator`